# Loading specific data from the store after loading data from an API

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx-effects

I have this `RXJS` effect in my project where on an action I'm loading an organisation from the server, and then attempting to select a bookmark from the `NGRX` store based on the `organisation ID`. At the end of the effect I dispatch my success action with the data.

```ts
selectOrganisation$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(OrganisationsActionTypes.SelectOrganisation),
    withLatestFrom(
      this.store.pipe(select(AuthSelectors.selectCurrentUser)),
      this.store.pipe(select(ContextSelectors.getContext))
    ),
    switchMap(([action, user, context]) =>
      forkJoin([
        of(user),
        of(context),
        this.organisationService.getOrganisationById(context, action.id),
        this.moduleService.getAllSimpleModules(context)
      ])
    ),
    switchMap(([user, context, organisation, modules]) =>
      forkJoin([
        of(organisation),
        of(modules),
        this.store.pipe(select(BookmarkSelectors.selectBookmarkByOrganisation, {
          userId: user.id,
          context,
          organisationKey: organisation.key
        }))
      ])
    ),
    switchMap(([organisation, modules, bookmark]) => [
      onSelectOrganisation({organisation, modules, bookmark})
    ]),
    catchError(error => of(onSelectOrganisationError()))
  ));
```

The issue is my success action never fires, and neither do I get any kind of `error` thrown.
I can breakpoint the effect in all of the `switchMaps` and see data **except for the last one, which never gets hit** so I'm suspecting I might have issues with my bookmark selector.

My bookmark selector looks like this, and at this moment in time there are no bookmarks in the array, so this function returns `undefined`.

```ts
export const selectBookmarkByOrganisation = createSelector(
  selectAllBookmarks,
  (bookmarks: BookmarkDto[], props) => {
    const bookmark = _.chain(bookmarks)
      .filter(b =>
        b.userId === props.userId
        && b.serverContext === props.context
        && b.organisationKey === props.organisationKey)
      .first()
      .value();
    return bookmark;
  }
);
```

To me, this seems a little messy, and I'm looking for some pointers as to how I can improve this code, and squash this bug at the same time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that last `forkJoin` not emits anything(from the definition)

> If an inner observable does not complete forkJoin will never emit a value!

follows that your selector should `complete`

I suggest using `take(1)/first` on the selector to complete it(also, in addition, try to use `startWith`(but I think `undefined` should be fine)).

Also, "action's" `switchMap` transfer to `map` - no need to "flatten"

Should work like this:

```
switchMap(([user, context, organisation, modules]) =>
  forkJoin([
    of(organisation),
    of(modules),
    this.store.pipe(
      select(BookmarkSelectors.selectBookmarkByOrganisation, {
        userId: user.id,
        context,
        organisationKey: organisation.key
      }),
      take(1),
    )
  ])
),
map(([organisation, modules, bookmark]) =>
  onSelectOrganisation({organisation, modules, bookmark})
),
```

For general adjustments: simplify it a little bit(if possible) - to much `ofs`, `switchMaps`, maybe take a look on difference between `zip/combineLatest/etc`